# Device check in sencha touch 2

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I'm sure I'm just overlooking this question but I cant seem to find how to check the device.
I want to check whether the device is either a phone, a tablet in landscape mode, a tablet in portrait mode or a other device (computer).

What I have is this:

```
if (Ext.platform.isPhone) {
    console.log("phone");
}

if (Ext.platform.isTablet) {
    console.log("tablet");
}

var x = Ext.platform;
```

But platform is undefined (probably because this is the way of Sencha Touch 1).

Does anyone know the correct place for me to access the device check?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[Sencha Environment Detection](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.1.1/#!/guide/environment_package) offers a large spectrum through simple means.

Instead of **Ext.os.is.Tablet**, you can make life easier via **Ext.os.deviceType** which will return:

- Phone
- Tablet
- Desktop

NB: this value can also be fudged by adding "?deviceType=" to the url.

```
http://localhost/mypage.html?deviceType=Tablet
```

**Ext.os.name** is the singleton returning:

- iOS
- Android
- webOS
- BlackBerry
- RIMTablet
- MacOS
- Windows
- Linux
- Bada
- Other

The usual ability of browser detection is available through **Ext.browser.name**.

Something I've only recently encountered, which I love is feature detection - allowing coding similar to Modernizr / YepNope based off ability of device. **Ext.feature** offers:

- Ext.feature.has.Audio
- Ext.feature.has.Canvas
- Ext.feature.has.ClassList
- Ext.feature.has.CreateContextualFragment
- Ext.feature.has.Css3dTransforms
- Ext.feature.has.CssAnimations
- Ext.feature.has.CssTransforms
- Ext.feature.has.CssTransitions
- Ext.feature.has.DeviceMotion
- Ext.feature.has.Geolocation
- Ext.feature.has.History
- Ext.feature.has.Orientation
- Ext.feature.has.OrientationChange
- Ext.feature.has.Range
- Ext.feature.has.SqlDatabase
- Ext.feature.has.Svg
- Ext.feature.has.Touch
- Ext.feature.has.Video
- Ext.feature.has.Vml
- Ext.feature.has.WebSockets

To detect fullscreen/app/homescreen browser mode on iOS:

```
window.navigator.standalone == true
```

Orientation **Ext.device.Orientation** and orientation change:

```
Ext.device.Orientation.on({
    scope: this,
    orientationchange: function(e) {
        console.log('Alpha: ', e.alpha);
        console.log('Beta: ', e.beta);
        console.log('Gamma: ', e.gamma);
    }
});
```

Orientation is based on Viewport. I usually add a listener which is more reliable:

```
   onOrientationChange: function(viewport, orientation, width, height) {
        // test trigger and values
        console.log('o:' + orientation + ' w:' + width + ' h:' + height);

        if (width > height) {
            orientation = 'landscape';
        } else {
            orientation = 'portrait';
        }
        // add handlers here...
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [Ext.env.OS's](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.env.OS) [`is()`](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.env.OS-method-is) method.

> Note that only major component and simplified value of the version are
>   available via direct property checking. Supported values are: iOS,
>   iPad, iPhone, iPod, Android, WebOS, BlackBerry, Bada, MacOS, Windows,
>   Linux and Other

```
if (Ext.os.is('Android')) { ... }
if (Ext.os.is.Android2) { ... } // Equivalent to (Ext.os.is.Android && Ext.os.version.equals(2))

if (Ext.os.is.iOS32) { ... } // Equivalent to (Ext.os.is.iOS && Ext.os.version.equals(3.2))
```

---

Alternatively, you can also use [PhoneGap Device API](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.7.0/cordova_device_device.md.html#Device)

Comment: I did see this way, but the problem with this is that I also want to specify whether the device is a mobile device or a tablet. Android for example can be running on both a tablet or a mobile divice.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer to it:

What seems to be the case is that Ext.os.is.(tablet/phone or something else) is true or undefined. If it is not the case it will be undefined.
I.a. `Ext.os.is.Tablet` is true when on a tablet and undefined when not.

So this is the answer I was looking for

```
if(Ext.os.is.Tablet){
        this._bIsTablet = true;
    }else if(Ext.os.is.Phone){
        this._bIsPhone = true;
    }else{
        this._bIsOther = true;
    }
```